# Use jquery ajax to post multiple variables and stay on same page

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am a beginner in coding. I  want to post multiple data using jquery ajax to a php file & remain on same page to process result(data). Data is either 1 or 0
Now I am successful in posting one variable using the following syntax:

```
$.post("test_wkshop.php", {item1 : $(item1).val() }, function(data){
// statement....

}
```

However for multiple data I am stuck, nothing happens. Here is the bad code:

```
$.post("test_wkshop.php", {item1 : $(item1).val(), item2 : $(item2).val() }, 
item3 : $(item3).val() function(data){
// statement....

}
```

I have tried related questions but I got confused due my present knowledge (e.g reference to JSON, etc which I haven't learn). Can anyone help identify my error(s). Thanks

Comment: Check your syntax. Looks like some curly braces aren't matched right.

Answer (score 1):

`item3 : $(item3).val()` was declared outside the braces, try separate the data into variable for more readability like so :

```
var data = {
  item1 : $(item1).val(), 
  item2 : $(item2).val(),
  item3 : $(item3).val()
};
$.post("test_wkshop.php", data , function(data){
  // statement....

})
```

Comment: Thanks but this is also not working. I have tried some combinations e.g. remove var, data:{item1....}; I have gone tru some recomendations such as this script:   $.post("test_all.php", {'mysch='+$(mysch).val()+'myid='+$(myid).val()+'mypswd='+$(mypswd).val()}, function(data) also. Right now, I dont have a solution to it

Comment: can you post mentioned combination

Answer (score 0):

```
<b>Item1:<b><br>
<input id="item1" name="item1" type="text" required required pattern="[A-Za-  
z0-9.-_ ]{5,10}">

 <b>Item2:<b><br>
<input id="item2" name="item2" type="text" required pattern="[A-Za-  
z0-9.-_ ]{5,10}"><br>

<b>Item3:<b><br>
<input id="item3" name="item3" type="text" required pattern="[A-Za-  
z0-9.-_ ]{5,10}"><br>

<p id='alarm' class='alarm'></p>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#item3").change(function()  {
       var mydata = {
       item1 : $("#item1").val(), 
       item2 : $("#item2").val(),
       item3 : $("#item3").val()
       };
       $.post("test_myitems.php", mydata, function(data){
           if(data == 1){
               $("#alarm").text('This combination is OK');
           }else{
              $("#alarm").text('Wrong combination. Recheck list');
           }
       });
   });
}); 
</script>
```